# Ogg file not playing multiple times on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, audio

I have multiple audio tags in a html file:

```
<audio src="/sound/file1.ogg" id="sound" class="file1"></audio>
<a href="#" data-audio="file1" class="play">
 <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
</a>

<audio src="/sound/file2.ogg" id="sound" class="file2"></audio>
<a href="#" data-audio="file2" class="play">
 <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
</a>

and so on ...
```

Play is triggered by the following function:

```
$('.play').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        audioCls = $( this ).data('audio');
        $('.'+audioCls).trigger('play');
    });
```

Everything works like a charm on desktop browsers. If you click the play button, it will play the audio every time you click it. On mobile however, it only plays the sound once and I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

As a side note: the audio files are extremely small (100 kb max) and only a couple of seconds long.

**UPDATE**

It seems that Android pauses the file after you play it once. You need to unpause it from the OS UI (notification area in the upper part of the screen) in order to replay it.

Is this some sort of a security feature? Can I bypass it from my responsive website?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up ditching the `<audio>` tag altogether and going for a more elegant JS solution.

```
<a href="#" data-audio="file1" class="play">
 <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
</a>

<a href="#" data-audio="file2" class="play">
 <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
</a>

<script>
 function cassettePlay(cassette){
     var cassettePlayer = new Audio("");
     cassettePlayer.src=cassette;
     cassettePlayer.pause();
     cassettePlayer.load();
     cassettePlayer.play();
 }

 $('.play').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var cassette = "/audio/" + $( this ).data('audio') + ".ogg";
     cassettePlay(cassette);
 });
</script>
```

It works!